# function currying vs an ordinary callback method

Tags: interface, callback, functional-programming, currying

I'm trying to understand how the programming technique known as *currying* differs from an ordinary callback interface (such as the Observer/Observable interfaces in Java, or the classic Visitor design pattern).

I understand what currying is, I just don't understand why it's uniquely useful to the point that it requires its own terminology and language support.

Could someone explain a programming situation that is better solved by currying than by a callback method?  What's the practical significance of the fact that currying uses a separate function for each argument?

[update:] to summarize the answers I got: currying comes part and parcel with the fact that functions are "first class" citizens, ie objects that can be created and passed around like any other object reference.  This makes it possible to return a function from a function, in other words currying.

As for the reason why currying is useful, currying provides a syntax to let you concisely decorate function calls so that derived functions can be created with minimal boilerplate code overhead.  Whereas in java you might create several overloaded or "wrapper" methods for each partial parameter set which ultimately invoke a master method containing all the parameters, currying provides a lighter syntax that lets you generate these "function wrappers" as needed in your code.

Comment: I don't know that it's better (except in an academic sense), it's just part of a different way of thinking about problems. Currying, along with other functional idioms, do have a way of allowing a skilled programmer to communicate an idea concisely without sacrificing expressiveness.

Comment: You might like to vote, accept, or comment on these answers.

Comment: @Marcin: I had asked for an example of when currying does what a callback cannot.  Still waiting on that...

Comment: @Magnus Does a callback provide partial application? No? There's your example. Now, can you provide me an example of what a chili can do that a car cannot?

Comment: @Marcin: The tautology you've given is obviously not very informative... I was hoping for a sincere example demonstrating a programming scenario showing the unique utility of currying in a way that is not easily emulated by standard existing Java techniques such as callbacks and overloading.  A partial application, for example, strikes me as very similar to an overloaded method that chains into other versions of the method.  In the absence of meaningful examples I have to conclude that currying is more of a convenience than a necessity.  Would you agree?

Comment: @Magnus Let me ask you a question: how would you emulate currying with a callback? You can't. That's how they are different. As to "x is more of a convenience" you could say the same of *literally any feature whatsoever* in any language not restricted only features necessary to achieve turing equivalence. Once again, I don't think you understand what currying or partial application are. They are nothing whatsoever like callbacks or overloaded methods.

Comment: @Marcin: It's not that currying and callbacks are the same, it's that the *use cases* of these techniques seem to overlap.  Whenever I ask what currying is good for, I get answers like yours stating it can be used to provide a mechanism that acts like a callback.  So to rephrase my question, what is another *use case* of currying that is different from the use case of a callback?

Comment: @Magnus It's use case is the same as that of partial application, because it is a form of partial application. You have a function which is generic, and you want to make it do something specific. Can you do that with a callback?

Comment: @Marcin: I see, so it's useful as a wrapper to the function.  Agreed that no longer sounds like a callback, that now sounds like a wrapper method.  So the gist I'm getting is: currying provides a syntax to let you concisely decorate function calls so that derived functions can be created with minimal boilerplate code overhead.  Does this sound accurate?  And is it complete, or are there other use cases?

Comment: @Magnus Yes, you've understood how they work. That's all it is *as such*, but of course the point is that this one of a suite of features that enables a very concise style of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a point of language support.
In Java, for example, you can define all sorts of callback interfaces: one for parmeterless methods, one for methods with one argument, one for methods with two arguments, and so forth.

But wehn functions are first class citiziens, one does not need this: Single argument functions will do the job, because functions can be returned. Hence, one important interface in all "functional java" projects will be some interface of the form:

```
interface Fun<A,B> {
    public B apply(A a);
}
```

or the like that covers this pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Currying and callbacks are two completely different technologies.

Callbacks are essentially a synonym for "passing a function to a function" (i.e. higher-order function that consumes a function); currying is a form of partial application, i.e. a function  which isn't passed all of the parameters it expects returns a new function that only expects the free parameters.

Accordingly, they are not alternatives at all.

Currying is useful because it makes it much easier to concisely create functions that can be used as, for example, callbacks, or in a pointfree programme. It also means that you can, e.g. pass a callback to a function like `map`, and have a new function that applies your callback to every element of any list you care to pass to it.

Comment: This is still rather abstract to me.  The ability to make a partial function that executes a callback against every element in a map seems like the standard Visitor pattern, made slightly easier by Scala's functions being first class objects, but still easily emulated through Java anonymous classes.  Is there anything else I'm missing?  Maybe parallel performance implications, or flexibility in compiler techniques?

Comment: @Magnus A partially-applied function does not execute a callback. Repeat that until you remember it.

Comment: @Magnus You are seriously confused. What do you think is the connection between a curried (or partially-applied) function, and a callback?

Comment: of course I'm confused, that's why I took the time to ask a question on SO.  Re: the connection I see between currying and a callback -- you just used the word "callback" 3 times in your description of how curried functions are used, it's not fair to pretend these are totally disjoint concepts.  Giving me a mantra to chant does not do anything to illuminate the difference either.

Comment: @Magnus I actually don't use the word callback at all when describing currying. I describe how currying is a convenient way to create a function that can be used as a callback. By your argument, all functions are "like callbacks".